# android 2.2 to 1.6?

Tags: android, android-version

I have been developing an android app. I had chosen 2.2 as the version. I have not used any advanced features that are specific to 2.2 or above. I want my app to work with 1.6 and above. What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Use minSDK 4 in manifest file

Comment: So why don't you just change the SDK version to 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complement preview answers.

android make upward compatible your code automatically as much as possible (not always).
But lowering the api level of an app. **Can be a task from simple to nightmare to execute**, all depends if your code use a lot of specific 2.2 ...
That's means changing API level or android.jar in your project may be far to be enough.

good luck

Answer (score 2):

You should read this http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/versioning.html

Answer (score 1):

Open the AndroidManifest.xml file and change to :

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

At first you should set `android:minSdkVersion="4"` in the Android Manifest file.

Next step is to do some testing on an android vm with version 1.6.
Even better would be to test on a real device, but the compiler should give you enough hints what to change in your program.